# How can I change "Sale" label to"xx % Off" in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3, opencart-3

I am using Opencart 2.3.0.2. When I add Special price for a product, I can see a "Sale label" on the product. I want to change the "Sale" text to "% Off". Where can I find the file to make the specific change without using an extension.

I know MVC, i can code php logic for the % Off thing, I just need to know where to make the change, as I haven't worked earlier on Opencart, and i'm less familiar with it's directory structure and organization of files.

Comment: There's no label by default in OpenCart. it's probably a feature of your custom theme / extension.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit catalog/controller/.....php file in which you want to display sale in %.

find for $special calculation in controller file manipulate it to calculate sale in % and display it in respective .tpl file where $special is displayed.

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: There is no label by default in Opencart to calculate as per % special price. Kindly check question properly and then give answer appropriately.

Comment: @VipulJethva, Sale label replaces $special ,so as he ask for where to make changes I answered him accordingly and as he is a MVC developer he can my logic.

Comment: Yes, right but first of all, you have to mention that there is no default functionality of label(%) then after you give him to answer the question.